# AngularJS ngoptions dropdown

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

So I am trying to create a dropdown selection menu in angularJS. I can list the contents using ng-repeat:

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
<tr ng-repeat="food in foods">
<td data-title="'Name'">{{food.name}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

which displays for me a list of foods. I would like to turn this into a selection instead. 
However no matter what I try it doesn't seem to display.
here is what I had worked on so far:

```
<select id="food_select"class="form-control"
            ng-model="food"
            ng-options="item as item.name for item in food track by item.id">
<option value="">(Pick food)</option>
            </select>
```

Here is how I am getting the data:

```
 function getFoodList() {
            FoodService.getFoods().then(function (_data) {

                $scope.foods= _data.foods;
                 console.log("foodlist"+JSON.stringify( $scope.foods));
            });
        }
```

and here is a json sample:
"id":"540894f9b2a136082606e5f0","created_at":"2014-09-04T16:36:09+0000","updated_at":"2014-09-04T16:36:09+0000","name":"bananas"

Comment: Should it be "foods" here... `... for item in food ...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aanders50/U3pVM/8923/)**

Where `option` is like your index value of the array food.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <select ng-options="food.option as food.name for food in foods" ng-init="index = 0" ng-model="option[index]">{{food.name}}</select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.foods = [{
        option: "1",
        name: "apple"
    }, {
        option: "2",
        name: "orange"
    }, {
        option: "3",
        name: "chicken"
    }];
```

Comment: This is helpful but how do I use it without an array? i am getting my data from a foodlist function

Comment: Also how do I do it without ng-app?

Comment: first off, you always must have an `ng-app` to even use AngularJS, its like using `main (void)`. And define this food function for me as that doesn't help a lot haha.